# how to run npm/grunt command from jenkins

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jenkins, gruntjs

I'm new to this area and was trying to run the following commands from jenkins:

```
npm install
grunt quickStart
```

So far I've a jenkins running on a window machine as a window service and I've also installed NodeJs plugin for jenkins.

However, I'm stuck and quit confused following instructions [here](https://weluse.de/blog/continuous-deployment-with-yeoman-and-jenkins-part-ii.html), its asking me to to add one or mode nodeJs installation and I could not find those setting and not even sure if I even need them in the first place.

Here is the bit that's asking me to do: 
[image]

I cannot see this setting for the jenkins job I create. Is there an easy way to run those command in jenkins from a `.bat` or `.sh` script, a `.bat` would be recomended since I'm on window machine.

Note : I've already checked out a project using git in jenkins!!!

Thanks

Comment: This option comes only in freestyle project not on the pipeline.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**"its asking me to to add one or mode nodeJs installation and I could not find those setting and not even sure if I even need them in the first place.**"
I don't think you need that  I have pointed jenkins to the node installation folder an nothing more.., for this you go to Manage Jenkins->Configure System->NodeJS->NodeJS installations.. type in any name you like and point to where the node home folder is.

[image: node home directory]
 **...cannot see this setting for the jenkins job I create...**

Once you have configure that in your jenkins configuration you should have that configuration available like so:

[image: node in project]

**...Is there an easy way to run those command in jenkins from a .bat or .sh script, a .bat would be recomended since I'm on window machine**
I'm sorry don't get what commands are you referring to... 
so summarizing :

1. you have to tell jenkins where you have your node installation
2. use that configuration in your jobs

hope this helps...

Comment: Please Restart Jenkins After this step " Manage Jenkins->Configure System->NodeJS->NodeJS installations, Add NodeJs  Installtion" . Restarting Jenkins will help  to populate list of Nodejs versions.

Comment: @yokodev This answer was very helpful. Your use of screenshots was especially useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The way I made it, was trough execute shell, as the build tool for nodejs is npm, I simply wrote a shell script that instructs jenkins to run npm install in the workspace directory inside jenkins where it clones the git repository and then to zip and move the package if successful to another folder.