# How to execute NPM command in Jenkins via shell

Tags: javascript, testing, jenkins, npm, automated-tests

I am getting a syntax error when trying to execute the "npm" command

```
Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/projectName/npm test
                                                     ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Here is the Jenkins Build shell command that I used:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node

Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/kaleidoscope/npm test
```

Can anyone explain what happened?

Comment: what output does `sh('which npm')` have?

Answer (score 3):

This stack question basically gave me an answer. 
I didn't't install NodeJS plugin.

[how to run npm/grunt command from jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919364/how-to-run-npm-grunt-command-from-jenkins)

So, to trigger npm commands in Jenkins install and configure NodeJS plugin.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin