# npm not found error in jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job, where I give npm install. The script goes like :

```
node {
    stage('Configure repo') {
        sh 'npm install'
    }
}
```

I am getting error

```
/mnt/jenkins/workspace/project/proj/dura/script.sh: 2: /mnt/jenkins/workspace/project/proj/dura/script.sh: /usr/local/npm: not found
```

Even I tried giving `sh '/usr/local/npm install'` But still the same.

Please help

Comment: 1. did you install npm? (for jenkins user)  
2. did you set up the environment?  
3. did you tell Jenkins to use which NPM?  
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919364/how-to-run-npm-grunt-command-from-jenkins

Comment: @OnurGokkocabas - yes its working fine in my freestyle jobs. only pipeline job has got issue

Comment: did you try putting it into a wrapper? `nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'Node X.Y', configId: '<config-file-provider-id>') { sh 'npm install' }`

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
sudo -u jenkins which npm
```

You should see `/usr/bin/npm` or some other path to `npm` as the result. if not, run this command:

```
sudo apt install npm
```

This often happens when you don't specifically install `npm` after installing `node`. Because `node` installs an instance of npm in your home, which other user's will not have access to. Then you feel you already installed `npm` but the fact is, you didn't!